# Does anyone know or have a timepicker for Polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, timepicker

I need a timepicker with this format: `HH:mm:ss`.

Please write the link down were I can find it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While there's talk in the vaadin community about having a [time picker](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker/issues/245) along with the vaadin datepicker, you can checkout this https://www.webcomponents.org/element/fooloomanzoo/datetime-picker/demo/demo/index.html which will provide you the time in this format: `HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

[Web Components](https://www.webcomponents.org) is a place where people can upload any custom elements that they have created for use by others. There is a [paper-timepicker](https://github.com/bendavis78/paper-time-picker) here.